# Textbox Not Recognizing Contents Of Text Paste

Tags: wpf, textbox, copy-paste, word-wrap

I looked at all of the other similar titled questions and did numerous searches but cannot find anyone else having the problem I am.

I have a WPF textbox that I want to be able to past multi-line text into. The accept returns and accept tabs is set, but for some reason the textbox is not recognizing that the text has been entered and will not allow horizontal scrolling if I have the text set not to wrap (text wraps if I allow it, but do not want that). I even tried binding to a scrollviewer with no success.

Any ideas? I even forced the scrollbars as visible, but they do not recognize that text is not showing (if I copy the contents back... they contents are definitely there)

Here is my XAML for my textbox as is:

```
<TextBox 
  Name="convertCode" 
  Margin="12,12,0,0"
  Height="305" 
  MinWidth="300" Width="1103" 
  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
  AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" 
  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="" 
  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
```

(I am using C# 4.0 in VS2010 SP1)

Comment: No repro on this, pastes as expected.

Comment: Try pasting this line... and see if it will scroll right for you to see the end of it (The width used to be a lot smaller, but this one still will go off the side)...

Comment: queryCommand.Append("    (A.[Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(YEAR, -50, @PREDICTIONDATE) AND DATEADD(YEAR, -1, @PREDICTIONDATE) and MONTH(A.[Date]) = MONTH(@PREDICTIONDATE))");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shoot, I think I figured it out... I was trying to use one of the WPF themes from Codeplex and that appears to be goofing up the horizontal scroll. When I turn it off, it works like I am used to... sorry everyone. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem lays in the wrapping container. Did you placed the `TextBox` inside a `StackPanel`?

If so, try replacing it with a `Grid`.

Comment: Nope it is in a Grid. That would have been a great thought though.